# How to select option from datalist in Cypress

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cypress

I have a datalist with some options and I want to select the first one using Cypress. How do I do that?

I *need to* click on the option, simply typing in the value is not what I want, because when an option is selected, a Javascrip function is called. So it's more like How do I click on a datalist option using Cypress?

```
cy.get('#foods').first().click({force:true})
```

Does not work.

Comment: If you provide sample html of the datalist, it would help.

Comment: Please do not remove the ruby-on-rails tag, it may be relevant to the way the test needs to be approached.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming the Ruby datalist is like this

```html
<datalist id="foods">
  <% Foods.all.each do |food| %>
    <option value="<%= food.name %>"></option>
  <% end %>
</datalist>
```

gives this in the DOM

```html
<datalist id="foods">
  <option value="Lamb">
  <option value="Beef">
  <option value="Fruit">
</datalist>
```

You can get the first option with

```js
cy.get('#foods')                // gets the outer datalist
  .find('option')               // returns all options inside
  .first()                      // take the first
  .click({force:true})
```

for other option, e.g 3rd

```js
cy.get('#foods')                // gets the outer datalist
  .find('option')               // returns all options inside
  .eq(2)                        // take the third
  .click({force:true})
```

---

The `{force:true}` is only required because the list is not opened.

It may be better to open it first and click without force, as a page error can be masked by using `{force:true}`.

```js
cy.get('#foods')                // gets the outer datalist
  .invoke('show')               // open list
  .should('be.visible')  
  .find('option')               // returns all options inside
  .first()                      // take the first
  .click()
```